# How to add A migration if you have more DbContexts in dotnet core 2?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, package-managers

I am using dotnet core 2 and visual studio 2019 and I have several db contexts. But I want to add a migration to the MedicalDbContext. And I have also more default projects. But the right default project is HepEngine. So I select that project als default project in Package manager.

And in the command prompt: PM>Add-Migration add-echeq-alert-action-extraProperty -c medicalDbContext -s

But then I get this error:

```
Add-Migration : Missing an argument for parameter 'StartupProject'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
At line:1 char:72
+ ... Migration add-echeq-alert-action-extraProperty -c medicalDbContext -s
+                                                                        ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Add-Migration
```

So what I have to change? Thank you

Comment: This is helpful - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one DataContext, you need to specify for which context the migration should be created. For my projects, I'm using this code

```
add-migration YOURMIGRATIONNAME -context MyDbContext
```

where `MyDbContext` is the name of your context.

You can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell).